# WiFi network: I can't even come to a point to input login and password

Tags: wireless-networking

There are two networks in that place: 1. For guests. 2. For those who have a network certificate.

I have such a certificate. But I can use neither network.
My equipment seems to be ok as in a cafe I can connect without any problems.

But here the network don't ask me for login or password. It tries to establish communication but never comes to the point of login.

The administrator told me that the network will not work with Windows XP. I suppose it is a nonsense.

Cold you suggest me how to reveal what the problem is?

Comment: The network administrator has told you it won't work with your OS and you are asking us to help you? Additionally, your post doesn't give us any details about the network or your computer. You are making it impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Of course I'm asking. WiFi is  just a set of standards for implementing wireless local area network. Is anything wrong with XP here? I doubt. Bu the way, what steps should I undertake to diagnose the problem?